# Connectivity graph of a combinational circuit

Tags: graph, connectivity, vlsi

I am reading the book called, "VLSI Physical Design: From Graph Partitioning to Timing Closure" by Andrew B. Kahng, Jens Lienig, Igor L. Markov, and Jin Hu.

In that book, there is a picture of a combinational circuit like shown in Fig 1.

[image]

For the combinational circuit in Fig 1, the authors show the connectivity graph as shown in Fig 2 below.

My question is, there is no connectivity directly between gates x and y. In that case, why does the graph show two edges between gates (or nodes) x and y ?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While there is no direct connectivity between x and y (such as x feeding y), the net N1 connects three nodes: a, x, and y. So, as all three are electrically equivalent, you must preserve the connections for the relationship among all three nodes. Therefore, for N1, you need an edge between a and x, an edge between a and y, and an edge between x and y. Similarly for N2, as it connects b, x, and y, you need an edge between every pin pair among b, x, and y.

In the general case, if you have a multi-pin net, a net that connects multiple nodes, then you will need to have an edge between every pin pair:

"A p-pin net is represented by (p choose 2) total connections between its nodes"
-- connectivity graph definition on p.28.

As an aside, you can see that this is a tedious process and the number of edges can quickly grow in this model. If you use a hyperedge and hypergraph model, however, then you only need one hyperedge to represent N1 and one hyperedge to represent N2 (versus the three regular edges).

I do also want to point out that this connectivity definition is very general, and in some cases, the edges between x and y can be removed. For instance, if you are performing timing propagation (e.g., arrival time) on N1, then you only need a directed edge between a and x and a directed edge between a and y.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Dear Jin Hu, I am still not sure why we will have a direct connectivity between X and Y, since the circuit in Fig 1 does not have a direct connectivity.  Is there a graph theorem that tells that we have to assume this connectivity between X and Y?

Comment: Hi Kori, by the connectivity graph definition, X and Y are connected by both nets N1 and N2. Take net N1: its pins are a, x, and y, meaning that a, x, and y are considered "equivalent" (e.g., electrically). Therefore, all three pins (or nodes) must be connected to each other. So,to represent the connectivity of the net, there exists an edge between a and x, an edge between a and y, and an edge between x and y. The edge between x and y exists because of the definition of the connectivity graph (p.28). However, as I mentioned in the response, this definition is general (see next comment cont'd).

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you may use the given connectivity graph definition to encode your circuit, or you may choose to omit certain edges to fit your purposes. For example, for placement, you need all three edges so the three nodes stay close together (assuming no hypergraphs). That is, only keeping (a,x) and (a,y) would imply that (x,y) are not connected, and then can potentially cause x and y to be placed further apart. However, if doing timing analysis, then you do not need to keep (x,y), as timing will not propagate from x to y (or vice versa).